# Force bar numbers below the staff and chord names above in LilyPond

Tags: notation, lilypond, engraving

In [the documentation for the bar number engraver](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/internals/bar_005fnumber_005fengraver), it's quite clear that the bar numbers were only ever intended to go above the staff.  How do I override that behavior?  It would make a part I'm working on look much cleaner (when they're set to the top, they make a habit of floating way above the main staff when the ossia staff is active in a system but not visible).  [This reddit user also found nothing useful except a suggestion of "make sure the bars line up between staves and fake the measure numbers](https://old.reddit.com/r/lilypond/comments/a3cp2f/bar_numbers_below_the_staff/), which only could work in highly specific cases.

Related, can I force chord names to display above the staff?  It looks confusing when they display below the staff.  The [sample lead sheet](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/displaying-chords) and all the surrounding snippets have the chords above the staff, yet my part keeps placing the chord names below the staff.  I suspect that the ossia staff is causing issues here as well.

Something from the [aligning objects documentation](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/aligning-objects) seems like it should be useful in both cases, but I'm not sure how to apply it to the actual project I'm working on.

Comment: You can add a Dynamics context below your staves and add the engraver to it that renders the bar numbers. Equally, you can try to shift the chord names using `\consists`. I will give an answer later when I have proper internet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the bar numbers moved below the score, there are two approaches. The first would be to just use `\override BarNumber.direction = #DOWN` to shift the standard bar numbers down. The second approach adds a centred bar number for each bar below the score. This second approach is best described in [this snippet](http://lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Item?id=932).

For the first approach, you can use the following code:

```
\version "2.18.2"

\score {
  <<
  \new Staff {
    c'4 d' e' f' g' a' b' c' d' e' f' g' a' b' c' d' \break 
    e' f' g' a' b' c' d' e' f' g' a' b' c' d' e' f'
  } 
  >>

  \layout {
    \context {
      \Score
      \override BarNumber.direction = #DOWN 
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

As for the chord names, you should put your `ChordNames` context at the correct position and also tell the ossia context to be above or below another context. For example like this (note the named `Staff` and the reference in the ossia):

```
\version "2.18.2"

\score {
  <<
  \new ChordNames {
    \chordmode {
      c1 g d a e b f c
    }
  }

  \new Staff = "main" {
    c'4 d' e' f' g' a' b' c' d' e' f' g' a' b' c' d'
    << 
      { e'4 f' g' a' } 
      \new Staff \with {
        \remove "Time_signature_engraver"
        \override StaffSymbol.staff-space = #(magstep -3)
        \override StaffSymbol.thickness = #(magstep -3)
        fontSize = #-3
        firstClef = ##f
        alignAboveContext = #"main"
      }
      { e'4 f' g' a' } 
    >>
    b'4 c' d' e' f' g' a' b' c' d' e' f'
  } 
  >>
}
```

[image]

(Spacing could be nicer, but I hope you get the point.)